# Detecting if user is using proxies or vpn

Tags: proxy, vpn

It's possible to grab x-forward info from user.  Is there a way to detect a user is using VPN versus straight connection?  (i.e ipsec-nat-t, ESP or max-forward?)

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you might get somewhere if the vpn modified the actual tcp packets and left a signature which is possible, but there isn't much in the way of prebuilt tools to do this, and you'd have to essentially code your own webserver to see it.  Such a signature would really be a guess that the user was on a VPN not a certainty, and its entirely possible all popular VPNs are not detectable at all.